# How to make a script that backup System in Ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: bash, scripts, backup

I need a script that when I execute it, it will backup the system to a specific folder (destination).

I'd also like to exclude some files.

Answer (score 2):

If you use `rsync`, it will create a complete copy of all your files in another directory. It copies only changed files and is very fast that way. I use if for backup on servers and external hard drives:

```
rsync -avhE --delete --exclude=.cache . /media/mu/Gamma/Backup/
```

For scheduling, see `cron` and `anacron`.

Answer (score 0):

I use [lsyncd](https://code.google.com/p/lsyncd/)

It can be daemonizable, it uses rsync.

I use it like

```
 lsyncd -rsync /bin  "/media/xen/Expansion Drive/NOS/bin"
```

Aftet compile it and install check out

```
 lsyncd -help
```